# NotSupportedException: Could not convert constant 1 expression to string

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression, wcf-data-services

I'm manually building an Expression that uses IEnumerable.Where() to filter a DataServiceQuery from a WCF Data Service client-side proxy.

```
public class EntityIdentity
{
    public EntityIdentity(long id);
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    private long Id {get; private set;}

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is EntityIdentity && this.Id == (obj as EntityIdentity).Id;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Id.ToString();
    }
}

public class Entity
{
    public Entity()
    {
        this.Id = new EntityIdentity(0);
        this.Name = null; 
    }

    public EntityId Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Given the classes above, I am creating an expression that is the equivalent to the following where `EntityIdentity targetId = new EntityIdentity(1)`.

```
container.Entities.Where(e => e.Id.Equals(targetId));
```

When I attempt to resolve this query, the LINQ-to-URI translator throws the following exception:

```
{System.NotSupportedException: Could not convert constant 1 expression to string.
   at System.Data.Services.Client.ExpressionWriter.VisitConstant(ConstantExpression c)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.ALinqExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceALinqExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.ExpressionWriter.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.ExpressionWriter.VisitOperand(Expression e, Nullable`1 parentType, Nullable`1 childDirection)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.ExpressionWriter.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.ALinqExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceALinqExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.ExpressionWriter.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.ExpressionWriter.VisitOperand(Expression e, Nullable`1 parentType, Nullable`1 childDirection)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.ExpressionWriter.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.ALinqExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceALinqExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.ExpressionWriter.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.ExpressionWriter.Translate(Expression e)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.ExpressionWriter.ExpressionToString(DataServiceContext context, Expression e, Boolean inPath, Version& uriVersion)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.UriWriter.ExpressionToString(Expression expression, Boolean inPath)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.UriWriter.VisitQueryOptionExpression(FilterQueryOptionExpression fqoe)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.UriWriter.VisitQueryOptions(ResourceExpression re)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.UriWriter.VisitResourceSetExpression(ResourceSetExpression rse)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceALinqExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.UriWriter.Translate(DataServiceContext context, Boolean addTrailingParens, Expression e, Uri& uri, Version& version)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryProvider.Translate(Expression e)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.Translate()
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.QueryComponents(ClientEdmModel model)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.CreateExecuteResult(Object source, DataServiceContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state, String method)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.BeginExecute(Object source, DataServiceContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state, String method)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.BeginExecute(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.BeginExecuteInternal(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery.BeginExecute(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at ProAlign.ServerDataModule.Services.ModelSetQueryContext.<>c__DisplayClassa.<Execute>b__3()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()}
```

The aforementioned "constant 1 expression" refers to the value of the `targetId` variable.  What does this mean and what do I do about it?

Comment: `I am creating an expression that is the equivalent to the following where.` Could you add that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

The real problem may be that they query is not handling the EntityIdentity class as it may only be able to handle primitives. Perhaps it is trying to convert the class to a string.

My suggestion then would be to only work with primitives in the query.

In EntityIdentity change the Id property to public:

```
public long Id {get; private set;}
```

And then the query expression becomes this:

```
var result = Container.Entities.Where (e => e.Id.Id.Equals(1));
```

Comment: Note to the OP: EF will fail to translate EntityIdentity, too.

Comment: @nmat, I did see that, but I didn't believe it at first because there are a few errors in his code (a semicolon after the ctor and the wrong class name for EntityIdentity in Entity). But, after further thought, I think the problem is that the query is failing because it can't handle a non-primitive. I've updated my explanation.

Comment: When generating the URL, it appears to be calling `EntityIdentity.ToString()` which returns "1". This is the "1" referred to in the NotSupportedException.  I don't understand this; how can it not know what to do with a string?

Comment: @RaySaltrelli, it all boils down to the translater not being able to convert your type, and it might not be targetId, but it may be the items in the Container.Entities collection. Start with making your query simpler and not pass a class. This link mentions the exception: [Querying the Data Service (WCF Data Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd673933.aspx)